# SQL Server move data from Database B to empty Database A

Tags: sql-server

I have a question and I don't know if its applicable or not
if I have Empty Database let's call it (A) and have another Database called (B)
can I create a process to copy data from B to A automatically and keep data Updated always?

Comment: If database A is empty, why not just drop it and backup/restore database B as database A?

Comment: Needs a tag for which SQL you're using, and more specifics about the kind of tables/data you want to sync and how. Anyway it may still be better for DBA than SO.

Comment: SQL used is MS SQL Server and in need auto refreshed data automatically not manually by drop and restore